# Unable to configure Springs external jar in jboss 7 module.

Tags: java, spring, jboss

Added the module dependency in Jboss-deploymentStructure xml

JbossDeploymentStructure.xml used inside the Spring application

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
<deployment>
    <exclusions></exclusions>
    <dependencies>  
        <module name="com.ondot.cm.commons.commons" /> 
        <module name="com.ondot.cm.properties" /> 
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
```

Comment: Could you describe the problem a little

Comment: what is your question? what is the problem? is there an error message? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: We have a spring application which is deployed in jboss7 and we have a common jar file that is placed modules. But i'm unable to create bean for the commons jar. IS there a way we can create a bean for commons jar present in modules of Jboss 7?